# Suddenly, I need to give "Edit Access" to my Google App Web Apps so that my domain users are able to execute the Web App

Tags: google-apps-script

This hadn't been an issue for months, but the past few weeks this is happening.

When I publish the Web App I indicate:

1. Execute App as me
2. Anyone in  ha access

When anyone, logged into our google domain attempts to "execute" the Web app they get the "Google Drive / You need permission" screen (Unless they have, or I give them, "Edit Access" to the Web App Script.

Thanks for any insight here

Answer (score 1):

Google recently stepped up the security of App-script to help prevent phishing. Don't know if this helps.

- [Authorisation of Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)
- [OAuth Client Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)
- [Web app permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions)

Comment: Thank You !... I will dig into the links you provided